# Globally enable a font feature for libertine package

Tags: xetex, fontspec, libertine

The `libertine` package works with both PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX; with the latter it automatically loads and uses `fontspec` for OpenType font loading. Also with XeLaTeX, it's possible to load a font feature called Variant 01, which changes the ÖÜ characters to the style used in Hungarian (accents closer together). However, I cannot make this feature global:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Variant=01}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\addfontfeature{Variant=01}
\section{Ö}
\Large\textbf{Ö}
\end{document}
```

[image: ö]

Is there a way to use Variant 01 in the whole document, while retaining the convenience of `\usepackage{libertine}`?

Comment: Why using the `libertine` package is more convenient than using `fontspec` in the regular way (`\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}`)?

Comment: @JúdaRonén 1. In `libertine.sty` there are many more commands than that and I think they may be important. 2. Allows me to have very little difference between preambles for different engines.

Comment: @marczellm Almost all of the libertine.sty commands (which are not OpenType-only) are font-selection commands for localized use and it's unlikely you'll ever need more than one or two of these.  Adding default font features using fontspec would break the engine-compatibility you apparently desire.  If you want a font package that uses a Variant feature *and* suports [pdf]LaTeX, you can create it fairly easily by using the autoinst script to call otftotfm.

Comment: @user22108 By 'very little difference between preambles' I meant `\usepackage{iftex}\ifXeTeX\usepackage{fontspec}\defaultfontfeatures{Variant=01}\else\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\fi` because I'm using those anyway. Also it's convenient not having to remember the font filenames, only the package name. etc.

Comment: @marczellm By 'breaking engine-compatibility' I mean that the Variant feature is not available using [pdf]LaTeX unless suitable type1 fonts and support files are created. The problem isn't in libertine.sty; it's with the fonts and support files in the libertine package, which don't support the Variant glyphs for [pdf]LaTeX.

Comment: @user22108 OK, I see what you mean now. Yes, this means that the moment I type an Ö or Ü, I _have_ to switch to XeLaTeX. Funnily, my biggest LaTeX work so far, at ~50 pages has neither of these. But you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, because of the way the main font is defined:

```
\setmainfont
      [ Numbers = {\libertine@figurealign,\libertine@figurestyle},
        UprightFont    = *_R,
        ItalicFont     = *_RI,
        BoldFont       = *_\libertine@boldstyle, 
        BoldItalicFont = *_\libertine@boldstyle I,
      ] {\libertine@base}
```

This code is preceded by

```
\defaultfontfeatures{
   Ligatures = TeX ,
   Extension = .otf ,
   SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}
}
```

so no `Variant` is provided.

I made a couple of changes to `libertine.sty`, adding

```
\DeclareOptionX{defaultfeatures}{\def\libertine@defaultfeatures{#1}}
\def\libertine@defaultfeatures{}
```

in the option declaration part and then modified the above code as

```
\defaultfontfeatures{
   Ligatures = TeX ,
   Extension = .otf ,
   SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps} ,
   \libertine@defaultfeatures
}
```

Now, I tested with

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[defaultfeatures={Variant=01}]{libertine}
\begin{document}
\section{Ö}
\Large\textbf{Ö}
\end{document}
```

and here's the result:

[image]

This should be a feature request to the maintainer of `libertine`.

---

Update: in version 2014/02/11 of `libertine.sty`, the proposed addition has been implemented.

Comment: The most important convenience of the libertine package is that, if one avoids the fontspec-only features supported for legacy documents, the user can switch between fontspec and fontenc easily.  This would seem to be important during the period of transition from [pdf]LaTeX to XeLaTeX or luaLaTeX.  The OP can get the effect he wants by using fontspec and setmainfont directly, without fiddling with libertine.sty, which is already very complicated.

Comment: @user22108 The OP is aware of the possibility; however the question correctly points out that using `libertine` has some advantages over calling `\setmainfont` directly. If the package can be improved, it can benefit other people.

Comment: How should I do a feature request?

Comment: @marczellm Send an email to the package maintainer; you find the address in the documentation PDF of `libertine`