# Open Type - Font feature

Tags: fonts, fontspec, libertine, opentype

I'm currently using the Open Type Linux Libertine font. This font has many options available. In conventional word processing software, these options can easily be used when selecting the font. For example `Linux Libertine G:pnum=1&onum=1` allows to get proportional old style numbers.

In LaTeX, I can use the `fontspec` package and use the table below to select a number of options.
[image]

However, some options are not listed in this table. For example : `dbls`, `dash`, `circ`, `hang`, `thou`. . . The complete list of options available with this font is [here](https://www.numbertext.org/linux/fontfeatures.pdf).

How do I still access these options?

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{babel}

\newcommand{\text}{Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing.\par}

\begin{document}

\text

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can always add RawFeature={+circ;+hang;} etc for unusual features.

Comment: My understanding is that the typeface Linux Libertines has not been maintained for years. It is basically superseded by the typeface Libertinus, see https://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxlibertine/files/linuxlibertine/,  https://github.com/alif-type/libertinus, and https://ctan.org/pkg/libertinus-otf.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Tank you, but how does it work? For example I added `\addfontfeature{RawFeature={+dbls}}` in the preamble, but it didn't work out.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `\usepackage[defaultfeatures={RawFeature=+dbls}]{libertine}` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the font description says, dbls is a Graphite font feature. So you need for example a new lualatex (based on luahbtex) and the Graphite Renderer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine G}[Renderer=Graphite,RawFeature=+dbls]
\newcommand{\text}{Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing.\par}

\begin{document}

\text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem persists when using the Libertine package (which I prefer to continue using for the moment) even using the package with the command `\usepackage[defaultfeatures={Renderer=Graphite, RawFeature=+dbls}]{libertine}`. Note that in this period of containment, I have to work with the online editor Overleaf, which uses TeX Live 2019 (I don't know if this has anything to do with the problem).

Comment: Yet reading this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159790/globally-enable-a-font-feature-for-libertine-package), I don't see what's different between the two cases.

Comment: imho it won't work on overleaf, it doesn't have luahbtex yet. And the package will not work, it doesn't load the "G" fonts (on my system the font used is in the windows fonts folder and called `LinLibertine_R_G.ttf`).